# How to use std::thread inside a member function of an object in UWP C++/CX

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cx

How to create a thread using `std::thread` for UWP applications? Sorry I am having problem with the syntax needed for creating a thread of member function inside an object. I just started using c++/cx in visual studio. Here is my code:

```
void MainPage::increment(int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < val; ++i){
        m_timer4++;
        Sleep(100);
        textBox4->Text = m_timer4.ToString();
    }
}

void _4ThreadsUWP::MainPage::button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    m_timer->Start();
    std::thread th(&MainPage::increment, this, 5);
}
```

EDIT:

I am having these errors:

Error1:

```
'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

Error2:

```
Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
```

Comment: Your thread object goes out of scope immediately after creation. You should've joined it i.e. `th.join();`.

Comment: @Azeem even though, I added `th.join()` it still doesn't resolve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I gave up with `bind`-style syntax a long time ago, just use a lambda: `std::thread th([this]{this->increment(5);});`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I'll move it into an answer.

Comment: sure.. go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's wrong with your constructor call - the bind-style syntax is notoriously quirky and gives the worst possible error messages.

My suggestion is to avoid `std::bind` and its unholy brethren (such as this `std::thread` constructor) altogether, and just use lambda functions whenever possible. They have their own quirks, but they are generally more understandable, error messages aren't complete garbage and they have way more applications.

In this case, you can just do:

```
std::thread th([this]{this->increment(5);});
```

---

That being said, your code is wrong logically on multiple levels.

As already stated into a comment, since your thread goes immediately out of scope, you are going to get an exception because `std::thread` doesn't want to be destroyed until the thread ended or you explicitly detach the created thread from the thread object. So:

- either you call `join`, which in this case would make no sense, as now your main thread would be stalled waiting for the worker thread, so launching the thread is useless in first place;
- or you `detach` it, which is bad because now you can have runaway threads; if you close the application window, you may still have the thread running, operating on data that is being destroyed.

A better solution would be to move the worker thread at class level, start it (if it's not already started) on button click and join it at window close.

***But***: all this is useless anyway, since in almost every GUI toolkit (including UWP) the GUI objects ***aren't thread safe***. Invoking their methods from a thread that is not the main UI thread results in erratic behavior and crashes, and your code does exactly that.

There are ways to make safe cross-thread GUI calls (which generally boil down to passing messages through the GUI event queue) - [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive) may have some UWP-related suggestions - but it's like shooting mosquitoes with artillery cannons; in your case all you need is just a regular timer, with no thread whatsoever.